# Can I use SQL Server CE in a medium trust environment by just deploying the DLLs

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce, partial-trust

I've written an ASP.NET 4.0 application that is using a SQL Server CE 4.0 database. This is all working on my development environment using Medium Trust (same trust config as the hoster). On this machine, I've gone through the install process (downloaded and installed the MSI). I'm now trying to deploy this solution to my web hoster.

The code that is running is (this is a straight out copy of the Altairis Membership Provider:

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
using (var db = this.connectionString.CreateDbConnection())
using (var cmd = this.CreateDbCommand("SELECT PasswordHash, PasswordSalt FROM $Users WHERE UserName = @UserName AND IsApproved = 1", db)) 
{
     cmd.AddParameterWithValue("@UserName", username);
     db.Open();

     // Validate password
     using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader()) { .. snip.. }
 }
```

In the instance above, `db` is `DbConnection`, and `cmd` is `DbCommand`

I'm getting the following error:

> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckNReturnSO(PermissionToken
>   permToken, CodeAccessPermission demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Int32 create) +0
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Assert(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +61
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Assert() +28
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.KillBitHelper.GetKillBit() +231
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.KillBitHelper..cctor() +56
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.KillBitHelper' threw an exception.]
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.KillBitHelper.ThrowIfKillBitIsSet() +0
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory..cctor() +41
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory' threw an exception.]
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>   System.RuntimeFieldHandle.GetValue(RtFieldInfo field, Object instance, RuntimeType fieldType, RuntimeType declaringType, Boolean&
>   domainInitialized) +0
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, Boolean doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency) +180
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj) +8
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow) +232
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +88
>   Altairis.Web.Security.DatabaseExtensionMethods.CreateDbConnection(ConnectionStringSettings
>   settings) in DatabaseExtensionMethods.cs:19
>   Altairis.Web.Security.TableMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
>   username, String password) in TableMembershipProvider.cs:361

I've used a decompiler to look through the code, and it seems that the internals of SQL Server CE are looking for a registry entry and then trying to do a code `Assert()`.

Is it possible to use SQL Server CE 4.0 in a partial trust environment, by just `\bin` deploying the DLL ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided your hoster allows it - it is allowed by default in ASP.NET 4.0. Make sure you use assembly version 4.0.0.0 (and not 4.0.0.1). Read more here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/10/sql-server-compact-40-under-aspnet.html

Comment: I think what your blog post says that the reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe in <fullTrustAssemblies> in the global web.config file is added when .NET 4.0 is installed?? or is it when SqlServerCe is installed??

I'll have to check with my hoster as to whether this section is in the global web.config file...

Comment: I've just taken a look at the DLL (right clicked) and the File Version is 4.0.8482.1 - I only downloaded this version in the last few days. You mention 4.0 (not 4.1) in your blog post. Am I using the wrong version also??

Comment: It is not the file version, it is the assmbly version, look at the Reference in your Visual Studio project

Comment: Reference version in Visual Studio of 4.0.0.0

Comment: I meet the same problem, and checked the assembly version is 4.0.0.0. This answer isn't helpful